# Lodash: _.isBlank?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm looking for a way to test a value. I'd like it to behave this way:

```
_.isBlank(undefined) : true
_.isBlank(null) : true
_.isBlank(NaN) : true
_.isBlank('') : true
_.isBlank('a') : false
_.isBlank(0) : false
_.isBlank(1) : false
_.isBlank({}) : true
_.isBlank([]) : true
_.isBlank({foo: 'bar'}) : false
_.isBlank(['foo', 'bar']) : false
```

There is `_.isNil`, but `_.isNil('')` is false. `_.isEmpty` sounded promising but `_.isEmpty(0)` is `true`.
Of course, I could combine several tests together, but it would be cleaner to have it out-of-the-box, wouldn't it?

Comment: There's a rails method [`.blank?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F) that fits my requirements. I did not mention it here to be language agnostic. The point of Lodash **isn't** to provide access to hard-to-write functions, but to provide an *interface* with a set of clear methods to use, in a more functional code-style that out-of-the-box JS to increase it to higher level of abstraction language (like Ruby, Python etc.). I often need to test if a variable is not *empty* and I was looking for a BP.

Comment: Added context from lodash github issues: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/2261

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is no method in Lodash for your specific case.

You have to make a function if you want to translate your intention:

```
function isBlank(value) {
    return _.isEmpty(value) && !_.isNumber(value) || _.isNaN(value);
}
```

Results:

```
isBlank(undefined)
// => true

isBlank(null)
// => true

isBlank('')
// => true

isBlank([])
// => true

isBlank({})
// => true

isBlank(NaN)
// => true

isBlank(0)
// => false
```

Comment: You might also want to put that into a [lodash mixin](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#mixin). `_.mixin({ isBlank }); _.isBlank(0)`

Comment: what about?

isBlank(new Date) 
=> true